# Show view when toolbar collapses

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an activity with a `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar`. So, basically, a view that collapses when scrolling a `RecyclerView`.

What I need to do is to show a custom view when the view of the expanded layout is hidden due to collapsing.

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="#2196F3"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/header"
                layout="@layout/header_big_first_screen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Hello!"/>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categories_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the end, when the toolbar is expanded the view loaded with the  element is shown. When it is collapsed it doesn't . When it disappears the `TextView` inside `Toolbar`should be shown. Currently it shows all the time.

I've been looking in the events of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to add a listener when it changes size so I can check if that is smaller than a value and show that view.

This can be kind of tricky to explain but I believe I made myself clear. I've been googling around and cannot find anyone trying to do the same.

Comment: Could you just use the contentScrim?

Comment: @karaokyo the setContentScrim and its variations are for drawables and colors only, unless I'm missing something . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Taking a look at the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` source, the content scrim animations are triggered via an `OnOffsetChangedListener` on the `AppBarLayout`. So you could add another one to trigger alpha animations on your text view:

```
mListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if(collapsingToolbar.getHeight() + verticalOffset < 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbar)) {
            hello.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(600);
        } else {
            hello.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(600);
        }
    }
};

appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(mListener);
```

Comment: Totally worked! Much thanks! Mind the question: I'm looking at that implementation of `CollapsibleToolbarLayout` but how did you got to the value `(2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbar))`? Thanks again

Comment: It's the same trigger that the content scrim uses

Comment: Thanks for the solution @karaokyo Works like a charm! However while its alright for a mobile device, your if else cases don't get triggered on a tablet. Any idea why is that? 
Thank you.

Comment: ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight returns 0 before API 16

Comment: Please, use `collapsingToolbar.getScrimVisibleHeightTrigger()` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#getScrimVisibleHeightTrigger()) instead of `(2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbar))`. It is more readable and also takes into account `fitsSystemWindows` flag inside.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to replicate when the scrim is supposed to show (collapsed) or not (expanded), a better way is to override the `setScrimsShown` method, which is called every time inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout's `onOffsetChanged`, and add a listener to it like this:

```
public class CollapsingToolbarLayoutWithScrimListener extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {

    public CollapsingToolbarLayoutWithScrimListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CollapsingToolbarLayoutWithScrimListener(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CollapsingToolbarLayoutWithScrimListener(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr);
    }

    private ScrimListener scrimListener = null;

    @Override
    public void setScrimsShown(boolean shown, boolean animate) {
        super.setScrimsShown(shown, animate);
        if (scrimListener != null)
            scrimListener.onScrimShown(shown);
    }

    public void setScrimListener(ScrimListener listener) {
        scrimListener = listener;
    }

    public interface ScrimListener {

        void onScrimShown(boolean shown);
    }
}
```