# CollapsingToolbarLayout: Change menu item icon color when it is expanded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using **`CollapsingToolbarLayout`** in my project.

When the **`CollapsingToolbarLayout`** is expanded, By default it is white(i.e defined in `android:textColorSecondary` in `style.xml`).

**My question:**

> I want to change my menu item icon color.

[image]
here is my code:

xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:titleEnabled="false">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

MainActivity code:

```
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar_layout);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    //collapse map
                    //TODO: change share icon color - set white share icon
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    //expanded map
                    //TODO: change share icon color - set dark share icon
                    isShow = false;
                }
                }
            });
```

What i have tried so far:

1. [How to change toolbar icons color on collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809602/how-to-change-toolbar-icons-color-on-collapsing)

set `toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` but it changes back button color, while i want to change share button icon color.

2. [Set Toolbar Icon Colour Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020969/set-toolbar-icon-colour-programmatically)

`DrawableCompat.setTint` not work in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
private Drawable drawable;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    drawable = menu.getItem(0).getIcon(); // set 0 if you have only one item in menu 
    //this also will work 
    //drawable = menu.findItem(your item id).getIcon();
    //
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable.mutate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now in onOffsetChanged

```
        @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                        scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                        //collapse map
                        //TODO: change share icon color - set white share icon
                        isShow = true;
                        drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                } else if (isShow) {
                        //expanded map
                        //TODO: change share icon color - set dark share icon
                        isShow = false;
                        drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.shadow), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset)
        {
            Drawable upArrow = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.drawer_icon, null);
            if (offset < -200)
            {
                upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.option_menu_icon);
                drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
            }
            else
            {

                upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.option_menu_icon);
                drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
            }
        }
    });
```